# Spring Boot @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) dont work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, transactional

When i try to use:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

transaction not working, but if i use

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
```

everything works fine.

My code:

SpringBootAplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class SpringBootAplication
{
    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {              System.out.println(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.isInstrumentationAvailable());
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAplication.class, args);
    }
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    MyRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test()
    {
        repository.findById("name");
        System.out.println(TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus());
    }
}
```

Also i have a VM options: -javaagent:"spring-instrument-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar" for ASPECTJ.

And this is exception which i accept when try to get current transaction.

```
org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
```

Also my depend

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```

Comment: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Try adding this dependency in pom.xml , then try with aspectj

Comment: tried, nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `aspectjweaver.jar` agent like this: `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` should solve your problem.